# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backend'

Tags: python, django, heroku, module, hosting

Running "python manage.py collectstatic" for a Django app I hope to host on Heroku results in this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Code\Django\store\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Code\Django\store\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\collectstatic.py", line 161, in handle
    if self.is_local_storage() and self.storage.location:
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\collectstatic.py", line 215, in is_local_storage
    return isinstance(self.storage, FileSystemStorage)
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 246, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\storage.py", line 438, in _setup
    self._wrapped = get_storage_class(settings.STATICFILES_STORAGE)()
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py", line 366, in get_storage_class
    return import_string(import_path or settings.DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE)
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backend'
```

I tried following that path and saw that there was no python file called backend so I ran "pip install backend" which then installed. However, now I have another module not found error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backend.custom_azure'
```

When I try to install that too it cannot be found.

In case it is helpful here is my requirements.txt file:

```
Gunicorn==20.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
Django-Heroku==0.3.1
Django==3.2.8
asgiref==3.4.1
azure-core==1.19.0
azure-storage-blob==12.9.0
certifi==2021.10.8
cffi==1.15.0
charset-normalizer==2.0.7
cryptography==35.0.0
django-storages==1.12.2
idna==3.3
isodate==0.6.0
msrest==0.6.21
oauthlib==3.1.1
pycparser==2.20
pytz==2021.3
requests==2.26.0
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.2
urllib3==1.26.7
backend==0.2.4.1
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from .models import User, Comment, Listing
from .forms import RegistrationForm, CreateListing, DemandListing


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, "boutique/index.html", {
            "collection": Listing.objects.filter(available=True, buyer=None)
        })

def register(response):
    if response.method == "POST":
        form = RegistrationForm(response.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()
        return redirect("index")
    form = RegistrationForm()
    return render(response, "registration/register.html", {
            "form": form
        })

def look(request, item):
    return render(request, "boutique/look.html", {
            "item": Listing.objects.get(name=item)
        })

@login_required
def create(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.user
        if user.is_superuser:
            form = CreateListing(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid:
                listing = form.save(commit=False)
                listing.date = timezone.now()
                listing.save()
                return redirect("look", listing.name)
            else:
                return render(request, "boutique/error.html")
    form = CreateListing()
    return render(request, "boutique/create.html", {
            "form": form
        })

@login_required
def demand(request):
    message = ""
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.user
        form = DemandListing(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid:
            listing = form.save(commit=False)
            listing.buyer = user
            if listing.date <= timezone.now():
                message = "You have to pick a date in the future!"
                return render(request, "boutique/demand.html", {
                        "form": form,
                        "message": message
                    })
            listing.save()
            return redirect("index")
    form = DemandListing()
    return render(request, "boutique/demand.html", {
            "form": form
        })

@login_required
def mystuff(request):
    user = request.user
    bought = Listing.objects.filter(buyer=user, available=False)
    demands = Listing.objects.filter(buyer=user, available=True)
    return render(request, "boutique/mystuff.html", {
            "bought": bought,
            "demands": demands
        })

def about(request):
    return render(request, "boutique/about.html")
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.
class User(AbstractUser):
    watching = models.ManyToManyField("Listing", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.username}"

class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    about = models.ForeignKey("Listing", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Comment by {self.author} on {self.date}"

class Listing(models.Model):
    categories = [
        ("mens", "Mens"),
        ("womens", "Womens"),
        ("girls", "Girls"),
        ("boys", "Boys"),
        ("kids", "Kids")
    ]
    category = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=categories)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    buyer = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} for {self.price}"
```

Comment: please update your `models.py` `views.py` file

Comment: I've added those files